# Windows 11 VPNs failing with "(Code 56) Windows is still setting up the class configuration for this device"

Tags: windows, drivers, vpn, windows-error-reporting

I installed some VPNs and they worked a few days ago, but now all of the VPNs stopped working with my computer. I have tried several more VPNs such as Windscribe, Nord, Radmin. They all don't connect and gets stuck at connecting.

I checked the device manager and saw that the VPN drivers all have a yellow explanation mark and it says

```
(Code 56) Windows is still setting up the class configuration for this device
```

for most of the drivers.

I did a network reset, reinstalled the drivers by uninstalling, and ran the troubleshooter as well. None of these fixed the issue, VPNs still not connecting.

Is there a fix to this?

[image: Driver Error]

Comment: Welcome to SU. What research did you do before posting the question? Quick internet search `(Code 56) Windows is still setting up the class configuration for this device` brings up for example https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000038102/intel-nuc/intel-nuc-kits.html, https://appuals.com/fix-windows-is-still-setting-up-the-class-configuration-for-this-device/, https://thegeekpage.com/windows-is-still-setting-up-the-class-configuration/...

Comment: I assume you ran the Network Troubleshooter without any resolution to the problem?

Comment: If you can resolve the issue, please do [write an answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer). If not, please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1777558/edit) your question to add what exactly have you tried to resolve the issue, and with what results (exact error messages etc., please).

Comment: Hi, I did a network reset, reinstalled the drivers by uninstalling, and ran the troubleshooter as well. None of these fixed the issue.

Comment: *f not, please edit your question to add what exactly have you tried to resolve the issue, and with what results (exact error messages etc., please).*